# How can I create a print button in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Do you know a component that allows you to do it in Svelte JS ?

For exemple, like ReactToPrint, a print React components.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print what you have in the screen you can add a HTML button and call a JS function to execute this code

```js
window.print()
```

I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can print all of the window

```
window.print()
```

You can inset a button in your svelte like this.

```
<button on:click={() => window.print() }>Click to print</button>
```